# how to create secondary constructor in recycler adapter taking arraylist parameter in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFxLA.png)

I AM trying to create other constructor in recyclerView adapter but getting error
please tell me how to create secondary constructor in recycler adapter taking arraylist parameter in kotlin android studio

```
class CustomRecyclerAdapter constructor(
    val context1: Context,
    val topics: Array<String>,
    private var alist: ArrayList<Array<String>>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    constructor(sss: ArrayList<Array<String>>, ttt: Array<String>) : this(sss) {
        this.alist = sss
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layout)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.topicTextView.text = topics[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return topics.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var topicTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gir_topics_tvid)


    }

}
```

Comment: Please add code, not image.

Comment: added code please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use these constructors:

```
class CustomRecyclerAdapter constructor(
    val context: Context, 
    val topics: Array<String> = emptyArray(),
    private var alist: ArrayList<String> 
 ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    constructor(context: Context, sss: ArrayList<String>) : this(context, alist = sss) 

    // ...
}
```

In the primary constructor you need to specify a default value for `topics`. Also add `context: Context` parameter to the secondary constructor and pass it to `this()` when calling the primary constructor.

Comment: thank you so much  Bro  it worked.  wasted so much time on this. thanks a lot. God bless you.

Comment: Accepted your answer. once gain thank you! .